# Catholicism - How can I deal with the possibility of being on call on Sundays?

Tags: catholicism, sunday

I work for a large, [Fortune 500](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortune_500) company as a software developer. One of the pinch points is that we need to be 'on call' for one week at a time on a rotation and this might include Sundays.

We are not paid extra for being on call and the work can be done remotely at home. There is not always work to be done while 'on call'; it's just if there is a severity 2 bug then you will need to be available to investigate the bug. I still attend mass on those days. It's rare that this occurs on Sundays, because most of our customers do not work on Sundays.

It would be very inconvenient to change my rotation to exclude Sundays and given that it's rare to be called on Sundays, I'm wondering if this is really an issue from a Catholic perspective?

We are not called on Sundays for just any type of bug, but bugs just for things which may take the system down or pose massive security threats.

---

**Edit**: For clarity, the software I work on is not being used to support hospitals or emergency services, it's purely for commercial purposes.

I have talked to my local priest and he did mention that missing mass and working on a Sunday are two separate concerns as well. He did mention that I could attend a Vigil mass on Saturdays if I cannot attend on a Sunday. He said working on every Sunday is not acceptable but it's not the case for me, it's every 6 weeks at max.

I talked to my HR department and they said there is no legal way out of working on Sundays. The local laws apply and the local laws are more in support of employers in this situation and they also mentioned the contract I signed.

Comment: You're a software engineer? It wouldn't seem life-and-death necessary that the bug be addressed immediately on Sundays. Necessary work that can be done on Sundays is work like a doctor saving someone's life, firefighters putting out a fire (that can't wait until Monday!), etc.

Comment: Might you be able to bring this up with your manager? I wouldn't personally mind a colleague doing a Monday-Saturday on-call shift for religious reasons, with me having an extra Sunday tacked on every now and then.

Comment: @Geremia, that really depends on the case. Flappy bird goes down; not an emergency. Navigation systems for that fire truck or communications for those doctors go down: that's a bit different!

Comment: @Geremia: I work in software for retailers. If our software goes down, stores do not get replenished. Usually, nobody dies from that, but the disruptions are still *very* expensive for our customers. And yes, we do have 24/7 SLAs and developers on standby around the clock.

Comment: @Geremia I'm guessing you don't work in Software. Plus, necessary in terms of Sunday doesn't mean strictly life and death necessary only.

Comment: @user how quickly are you expected to return the calls?

Comment: @user I'm in the same situation as you, and my aunt also is on-call on weekends, and frankly, it is just a view of the spirit, if both of us sometimes do something else on sunday, *it's no big deal*. Plus it's unfair for your colleagues if for *personal and private* reasons, you make them work, or be on-call on sunday, instead of you.

Comment: Two important questions here: 1. Is the on-call for that day 24 hours, including waking you up from sleep? 2. How fast of a reaction time is expected? Needing to be available to examine a bug means having to be able to start with it right away, 24/7, withing a minute of receiving it, or it just meas you should to it that day, even if you start an hour or two later?

Comment: @Josiah Indeed.

Comment: @eques "_necessary in terms of Sunday doesn't mean strictly life and death necessary only_" What's it mean, then?

Comment: @Geremia It's rare for a software problem to literally be a matter of life and death, though it does happen in cases of infrastructure systems, medical equipment, air traffic control systems, nuclear reactors, and other high-stakes industries. But it's not a matter of literal life and death versus unimportant. A software outage can lead to enormous financial losses, causing businesses to downsize or shut down entirely: workers lose their incomes, bankruptcies, and home foreclosures result. If I knew a problem I could fix would cause a small customer to lose a lot of money, I would try to help.

Comment: OP stated that it's a Fortune 500 company. Such large companies are very likely to have operations running 24 hours a day,  seven days a week, both to cover workloads that can't be done during the day, and also to allow for international customers.  Sunday isn't Sunday everywhere in the world.

Comment: Words of advice: If you want to continue going to church on the weekends, do not apply for a job at Amazon or at the United States Postal Service.

Comment: an issue from a Catholic perspective?  you mean if God will be displeased that you work on Sundays?

Comment: @Geremia I'm not sure whether I can give a stricter definition than what necessary simply means. It's clear though from how the Church has talked about Sunday obligations that "life or death" is not the defining criteria (and would lead to absurdities if it were interpreted thus)

Answer (score 14):

Also a software engineer and Catholic here.

One thing I've said to my own employer is that I won't work on Sundays. I'm blessed in that I don't have your on-call obligations, of course!

The Mass that takes place the **evening before** is known as a "Vigil Mass". A Vigil Mass fulfills any obligations that would apply on the **following day**.

So, if your parish has a Mass on Saturday evening, you can go to that one and you've fulfilled your Sunday obligation.

Regarding working on Sunday, my view is that, if possible, you should arrange a call with your manager and discuss the possibility of different working hours that free you to rest on the Lord's day.

You should do this, because **even if they say no, you have now fulfilled a moral obligation**. You have made the effort to make the Lord's day holy; if the world and your work restrains you from that, and you've made all reasonable efforts to change this, the blame will not fall upon your shoulders.

I'm not a priest of course; as much as I love SE, I encourage all lay Catholics to consult their priest and the Catechism first and foremost for guidance over the advice of strangers.

Comment: However, being on call is not the same as working in general on Sundays. The latter would be planned, ongoing etc. Your points above make more sense in the latter case than the former.

Comment: That's a fair point. The above is definitely more applicable for actually working on a Sunday.

Though I might argue that being on call is, in and of itself, obstructive to the purposes and nature of the Lord's Day. I've only been on call a few times in my life but it certainly isn't conducive to rest, heh. And issues potentially come up when OP does eventually get called.

Comment: I like your answer; just want to highlight the **personal circumstances** factor which informs a moral situation that in turn contributes as a criteria for our moral decisions.  Examples: family obligation to provide income when this is the only job available at the moment, this job provides work-at-home flexibility allowing us to care for our young children, the knowledge of the estimated frequency of *actually* having to work on due to the on-call status, etc.  So if we cannot quit this job, have made reasonable effort, and have consulted a priest, I would say we are not in the wrong.

Comment: 100% agree with you @GratefulDisciple. We're all in different boats on the same stormy sea. In this modern era where the Sunday obligation isn't taken seriously at a societal level, it's far harder for us to secure that time, and the Lord certainly knows and understands this.

Comment: @ConnieMnemonic It somewhat depends on the organization but on call doesn't guarantee having to work and in many cases if on call frequently means each rotation you will have to work, the organization has some degree of disorganization which should be fixed or avoided (i.e by leaving). Being on call apart from the actual responding shouldn't actually be that disruptive to rest since you generally need to be contactable but otherwise can do what else you would like.

Comment: Also, it is not all work that is considered equally at odds with Sunday rest, but only unnecessary servile work (Which is not equivalent to work for pay)

Answer (score 7):

It is an issue, but the Catechism does allow for it:

> [2188](https://www.vatican.va/archive/ENG0015/__P7O.HTM). If a country's legislation or other reasons require work on Sunday, the day should nevertheless be lived as the day of our deliverance which lets us share in this "festal gathering," this "assembly of the firstborn who are enrolled in heaven."<sup>125</sup>
>
> <sup>125</sup> Heb 12:22–23 — *But you have come to Mount Zion and to the city of the living God, the heavenly Jerusalem, and to innumerable angels in festal gathering, and to the assembly of the first-born who are enrolled in heaven, and to a judge who is God of all, and to the spirits of just men made perfect.*

Comment: I did think about mentioning vigil masses and the like and how OP might organise his life, but it wasn't asked for.

Comment: I'd be tempted to close the question as seeking pastoral advice if this wasn't in the Catechism.  I'm in the same boat work-wise, software engineer at a fortune 500 company made to work an on-call rotation.  Somehow, in 20 years (where I average one or two callouts each rotation), I can recall only once been called during Mass - and that was during Our Lady of Guadalupe Mass.  So my unsolicited advice, echoing Padre Pio, Pray, hope and don't pick up the phone when work calls during Mass.

Answer (score 6):

There are two separate issues here: working on Sunday and attending Mass on those specific Sundays where you are on call; I'll only address the latter.

For Mass, I suggest that you familiarize yourself with the Mass schedules of the various local parishes and when you are on call, attend the earliest practical Mass, so that if a Sev2 bug comes up later in the day you will not lose your chance to attend Mass that day.  (There are other precautions you can take, like sitting close to the exit so you can dip out unobtrusively if need be, putting your phone on vibrate, and possibly even selecting your on-call church for the nearby availability of WiFi for your laptop.) I assume the priest who celebrates the earliest Mass in the neighborhood is used to hosting "attendees of convenience".

Your own priest may have other suggestions, such as attending a midweek Mass before or after you are on call. (Several commenters have also suggested Saturday evening vigil Mass.)

Comment: +1, and Saturday evening vigil masses, of course.

Comment: Saturday evening vigil masses are the way to go here, almost certainly. A midweek mass does not fulfil the Sunday obligation and I don't know many ways the Sunday obligation can be abrogated for OP.

Answer (score 3):

Prümmer, O.P., [*Manuale Theologiæ Moralis II* (14ᵃ ed.)](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=7184) (1955), p. 406 (§496) (my emphases):

> I. By reason of necessity of oneself or of another, whether this [necessity] be corporal or spiritual, [the following] are excused [from the precept to refrain from prohibited works on holy days]:
> a) farmers who because of a past or **imminent** storm need to immediately pick their corn or fruit. […]
> […]
> e) workers who need to watch over machines in large factories; repairers of bridges, railroads, etc., **if there is danger in delaying**. […]
>
> ---
>
> <sup>I. **Ratione necessitatis propriæ aut alienæ**, sive hæc sit corporis sive sit spiritus, excusantur:
> a) agricolae, qui ob praeteritam vel **imminentem** pluviam statim colligere debent segetes aut fructus. […]
> […]
> e) operarii, qui vigilare debent in magnis fabricis super machinas; restauratores pontium, viæ ferreæ etc., **si periculum est in mora**. […]</sup>

Thus, will your entire software "machine" halt if you don't address the bug immediately? Is there a "storm" of bugs that will cause an immanent danger to your computer system? If not, then you'd need to seek a [dispensation](https://www.catholicculture.org/culture/library/dictionary/index.cfm?id=33121) to perform such work on Sundays; speak with your priest.

---

The [Third Commandment](http://www.catholicapologetics.info/thechurch/catechism/TenCommandments-third.shtml) has two parts:

1. Hearing Mass on holy days (positive precept)
2. Refraining from prohibited works (negative precept).

Forensic/commercial works (*opera forensia*) such as buying and selling are prohibited.

Comment: "will your entire software "machine" halt if you don't address the bug immediately" that strictness is not quite implied by your source.

Comment: While I think your interpretation is perhaps a little strict, I adore the way you've approached this. I can definitely see OPs situation as "trouble has come upon me and I must act to protect my livelihood".

Comment: @eques In fuller context, yes. I added: "…repairers of bridges, railroads, etc., if there is danger in delaying."

Comment: Again, I will repeat my comment from above "I'm guessing you don't work in software" because your speculations from your source don't match how software works in reality. Engineers are too expensive to be on call just for giggles; engineers are on call because something critical may go wrong. The challenge is that you may not know how severe a particular interruption is until it occurs and someone has an opportunity to examine it.

Comment: @eques How doesn't that fall under "workers who need to watch over machines in large factories"?

Comment: I meant "will your entire software "machine" halt if you don't address the bug immediately? Is there a "storm" of bugs that will cause an immanent danger to your computer system?" Software engineers would be on call for analogous reasons to those who watch machinery in factories (however, note that software engineers is more mental than corporal work and thus less related to servile work). Also, you seem to assume that "if there is danger" applies to workers watching over machines, but that's not immediately apparent -- the semicolon may imply it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a Catholic answer, but a *scriptural* answer.

> [Jesus] said to them, "Which of you, having a son or an ox that has fallen into a well on a Sabbath day, will not immediately pull him out?" (Luke 4:5)

> <sup>23</sup>One Sabbath [Jesus] was going through the grainfields, and as they made their way, his disciples began to pluck heads of grain. <sup>24</sup>And the Pharisees were saying to him, "Look, why are they doing what is not lawful on the Sabbath?" <sup>25</sup>And he said to them, "Have you never read what David did, when he was in need and was hungry, he and those who were with him: <sup>26</sup>how he entered the house of God, in the time of Abiathar the high priest, and ate the bread of the Presence, which it is not lawful for any but the priests to eat, and also gave it to those who were with him?" <sup>27</sup>And He said to them, "The Sabbath was made for man, not man for the Sabbath." (Mark 2:23-27)

Frequently skipping meals, whether physical meals or spiritual meals (i.e. Mass), is not healthy... but **God Himself** acknowledges that sometimes one does what one must.

You are asking about a situation which *might* happen infrequently... or never. IMNSHO, anyone that would make a law saying "you *must* attend Mass according to such-and-such criteria", or saying that it is sinful to miss Mass due to circumstances not entirely in your control, is guilty of the same Legalism as the Pharisees, which *Christ Himself* spoke against. If that describes your church leaders, perhaps you would do well to take a close look at Scripture and see how your church's teachings compare to the teachings of God.

Indeed, I would be skeptical of any claims that one **must** attend Mass (to be Saved), period. Certainly it is better to attend Mass, but to paraphrase Jesus, 'Mass was made for man, not man for Mass'.

Answer (score -1):

There are many Catholic churches, for instance, Basilica of Our Lady of Immaculate Conception, Washington which offer Live TV Mass service. It is a blessing for those who are not able to attend the church on  a Sunday. Though the practice developed as a COVID- related dispensation, it is still in vogue.

Comment: Watching Mass on TV does not fulfill obligation.